# difference in verb collocation with exam

Tags: collocations

I have read three verb collocations with exam but cannot find the difference in meaning.

> 1. sit an exam/test,
> 2. do an exam/test, and
> 3. take an exam/test

I would like to know the difference in meaning for each phrase.
Secondly, What verb we use for teachers who design a test because I have learned that "make a test" is wrong. Then if I am a teacher and design a test for my students what shall I say,for instance, I .... a chemistry test yesterday.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do a quiz** is the least formal. *"Buzzfeed™: What brand of beer is your boyfriend?"* There are no consequences and the results are probably meaningless or just for fun. Young students may get an unannounced "pop quiz" as an incentive to read the assignments.

**Take a test** is what children do through middle school. They may take several tests each week to make sure they are keeping up with their homework and reading the assignments. A test typically will not take the entire class time to complete, and is announced ahead of time.

**Sit for exams** is the final for higher education like in college or university, or for a civil service promotion, or to earn a job license or career certification. The exam is strictly formal, including what type of pencil is used and how much time is allowed. It probably takes place in a location away from the daily classroom.

*Test* is interchangeable with both *quiz* and *exam*, but *a quiz* and *an exam* are opposite ends of the spectrum and not interchangeable. *Take (a test)* is universal, *do* is casual/informal, while *sit* is only used for certification or higher education.

As a teacher you will **give** the test to the class, but earlier you will **write** it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your variety of English. In the US, we do not say *sit an exam*. As far as I can tell, *sit **for** an exam* is acceptable. The two common ways I can think of expressing this in AmE are with *take* and *have*:

> - I took an exam yesterday.
> - I had an exam yesterday.

This is what the Longman Dictionary has to say:

> [test](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/test)
>   1 EXAM a set of questions, exercises, or practical activities to measure someone’s skill, ability, or knowledge
>   **test on**
>
> - We have a test on irregular verbs tomorrow.
> - Did you get a good mark in the test?
>
> ► You **take** or **do** a test. Don’t say ‘make a test’. To **pass** a test means to succeed in it, not simply to take it.

Personally, *do an exam* strikes me as odd. I wouldn't use it. But it's listed in the dictionary, so it certainly has currency.

As far as I can tell, *sit an exam* is BrE and perfectly acceptable among BrE users. Here's an entry from the Cambridge Dictionary:

> [sit](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sit) verb (EXAM)
>   ​[ T ] UK to take an exam:
>   *After I've sat my exams, I'm going on holiday.*
>   AUSTRALIAN ENGLISH *I sat **for** my exams today.*

I don't know what BrE users (and other varieties) think of *to do an exam*. Just to confuse you more, there is also *write an exam* (= take an exam). That's not used in the US, but I believe it is used elsewhere. Let's see what others say!

As for the second part, I disagree. Perhaps you misunderstood, but when the teacher or the professor creates the test, we can say that they ***make** the test*, in my opinion. I believe the dictionary entry above means that **students** *take* the test, but they don't *make* the test. In other words, the entry is trying to clarify that *take the test* and *make the test* are not the same.

It's also possible to say that the teacher *writes* the test (= creates the test). That's my AmE perspective. Again, let's see what others say!